# Issue with dependencies when trying to install Wine and Synaptic

Tags: installation, wine, dependencies, synaptic

I am running 12.04 ubuntu on a dual-boot with win 7 and i have been trying to install Wine
however I had a bunch of dependency issues.

So I then tried using Synaptic which will not install either because of similar dependency issues like libc6.

I then searched for them in the software center some were already installed others had not because of other dependencies on top of other dependencies.

I am trying to understand why I am getting these errors?  How can I just download the program without all of these loops?

Comment: can you share some of the errors you are getting, this will be helpful

Comment: clarify, whether you have downloaded from internet through browser, and you are trying to install that package, or you are trying to install through ubuntu software centre from it's own repositories.?

Comment: As Stephen Myall says, we need to see the error messages in order to be able to advise you on how to fix the problem. Please edit your question to include the complete and exact text of all error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using a terminal it should resolve any dependency automatically.

Just type `sudo apt-get install wine`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since Synaptic also resolves dependencies automatically, it's unlikely that just running that command in the Terminal will fix the problem. However, the *output* of doing so may provide useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove wine synaptic
sudo dpkg -P wine
sudo dpkg -P synaptic
sudo apt-get install wine synaptic
```

Here's what each command does:

1. Removes broken packages.
2. Removes `wine`.
3. Removes configuration files, so `wine` will be totally gone from your system.
4. Removes configuration files for `synaptic`, so it will be gone too.
5. Installs `wine` and `synaptic` again on your system.

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` does not remove broken packages. It removes packages that were installed as dependencies of packages that are no longer installed (and thus which are probably not needed anymore). To be useful, it should usually be run *after* removing packages, not before. Also, please note that you don't have to run 4 commands to remove `wine` and `synaptic`, delete their systemwide configuration files, and reinstall, you can use 1 command: `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install wine synaptic` See `man apt-get` for details.